# How to make array in Jquery and pass it as hidden field value?

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, hidden-field

I thought I can save data I get from data.result.public_id to an array.

I get many public_ids and would like to pass all those ids as hidden field value, but first I need to save them to an array. I use Cloudinary service to store images. When I upload 5 images to Cloudinary I receive back 5 public_id. Every time image uploaded I want to store public_id to an array.

Then in the controller I map all the data in the array and save every public_id in the database.

How to save public_id to an array?

```
<input id="public_token" name="public_token" type="hidden" value="" />

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.cloudinary-fileupload').bind('cloudinarydone', function(e, data) {
  var public_id = [data.result.public_id];
  $("#public_token").val(public_id);
 });   
});
```

Comment: please make your question more descriptive.

Comment: Make what right? We have no idea what data looks like or what is or isn't happening with code shown.

Comment: Please take a look, I described it better.